# Shapes doesn't show on canvas when drawn programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone

I'm trying to crate simple app for my Windows Phone device where I can programmatically draw some shapes on canvas. When I write code to define shape in xaml everything looks great but when I try to draw same shape in code, nothing shows on canvas.

Xaml code

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="TestApp.ResultPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="TestApp" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="14,10,10,86" Grid.Row="1">
        <Canvas x:Name="resultCanvas" Margin="10,10,10,0" Background="White" MaxHeight="590" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="590" Width="436" MaxWidth="436" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Canvas.Clip>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 436, 590"/>
            </Canvas.Clip>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
    <Button x:Name="drawButton" Content="Return" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,615,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="81" Width="456" Click="drawButton_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

C# code for drawing line

```
public void Draw()
{
   Line line = new Line()
   {
     StrokeThickness = 2,
     Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
     X1 = 100,
     X2 = 200,
     Y1 = 100,
     Y2 = 200,
    };
    resultCanvas.Children.Add(line);
}

private void drawButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Draw();
    }
```

Comment: The XAML and code as you posted here is just working fine. The problem and the probable causes cannot be deduced from the information you have given here. I would guess that your function which adds the line is not being called for whatever reason. Another guess is that your real XAML/code is substantially different from what you posted here...

Comment: I added missing code. As far i can tell function is called and theoretically is working fine.

Comment: That is odd. Your code looks sound. There must be something else at play. Just some suggestions: Try putting the button in its own grid row. Try set the canvas background to a "visible" color such as red, so you can verify the Canvas really being visible and having the appropriate size (the canvas should be okay from what i can gather from the XAML, but who knows). Check if the canvas has a RenderTransform/RenderTransformOrigin that causes the line being drawn off-screen. Try setting Canvas.SetLeft() and Canvas.SetTop() for the line explicitly to 0 (it should be by default, but who knows).

Comment: You might also first try drawing multiple lines/shapes at different coordinates on the canvas to spot issues regarding coordinate transformations. What you have is not so much a question demanding an answer, it is more a situation requiring trouble-shooting...